# how to add attachment from server to phpmailer

Tags: php, css, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to attach files to my email using PHPmailer, I used the following code to attach the files:

```
    $countfiles = count($file_paths);
    for($x = 0; $x < $countfiles;$x++)
    {
    $mail->AddAttachment($file_paths['details'][$x]);
    }
```

where the value of the variable $file_paths['details'][$x] is:

/home5/aserver/public_html/website/style.css

but for some reason, it's not attaching to the mail, the mail does get sent to the emails.

Comment: Are you sure that the path is right? Are you using the path from where the PHP file is located?

Comment: @HenkdeJager Yes, I'm very sure as I do a scandir function so I could get the file path then I save it in the file_paths array. I just changed the names in the sample file path.